# Redirecting subdomain to subdirectory through htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've been trying to redirect a subdomain to a subdirectory through htacess..

I have a domain lets say `sub.domain.com`  and the directory `domain.com/site/`
I want to redirect sub.domain.com to domain.com/site not changing any url, simply redirecting in a SEO friendly way.

I've tried a redirect 301 rule but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 wiki.comp.tf(.*) comp.tf/wiki$1
```

If that does not work, an alternative option is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wiki.comp.tf
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://comp.tf/wiki$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Some potential options for you using actual names:

```
Redirect 301 wiki.comp.tf comp.tf/wiki
```

Comment: Thanks, as I've said above,  I've tried both yours and starkeen solution but it still displays the same error on the subdomain "server DNS address could not be found."

Comment: What are the actual domain and directory?

Comment: wiki.comp.tf is the subdomain which I want to redirect to comp.tf/wiki , I've changed those in your and starkeen code obviously to match my domain but I haven't been sucessful. Wondering if this has anything to do with my VestaCP setup but I've gone through it all 3 times and didn't find any issue

Comment: I've updated my previous options with the correct names now, just in case. I've also added one other simple 301 redirect.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, apparently I think I also forgot to set it up properly on cloudflare and didnt give it enough time to propagate the dns changes, so I think that was the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1 [L]
```

This will internally redirect

- sub.domain.com

to

- /site/

Comment: Should I put this on the htaccess of the main domain or the htaccess of the sub domain, because Im using VestaCP on a VPS and it automatically creates different directories for each domain/subdomain created. And if I have to put it on the main htaccess what should I do about the htaccess of the subdomain directory?

Comment: You can use this inside the subdomain/.htaccess.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both yours and thickguru solution but it still displays the same error on the subdomain "server DNS address could not be found."