# Overwriting existing url with another

Tags: .htaccess

I have an Ecommerce-Store and I want to overwrite an URL.
So I click on a link , and then the site opens with the url
http://www.myurl.de/order,
but I want the URL
http://order.myurl.com (subdomain).

I'm not sure how I can rewrite the existing url with the other one.

Kind regards
Tim

Comment: why would you need this, any strong reasons behind this? it's more complicated to work with sub-domains later. Have you tried to search the information how to make redirects with mod-rewrite in .htaccess before asking the question, what code do you have so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting subdomain to subdirectory through htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460537/redirecting-subdomain-to-subdirectory-through-htaccess)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting Subdirectory to Subdomain with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415896/redirecting-subdirectory-to-subdomain-with-htaccess)